# how to update view each time when i am getting response from .net server byu using async task?

Tags: android-layout

my aim to get the message with image in background and adding to that in list.

By this perpose i am using Async task to get the message and image in background.

The problem is when i am adding the message with image to view.the view is over ride every time.and it displays only last message with image only.

the view is not updated every time.

eney one please help me,if u don't understand the problem

please add comments.

thanks in advane

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to mess with the view manually, there is no need to add the new item (view) to it directly!

In your asynctask's `postExecute` method you should simply append the newly arrived data to the `ArrayList` (or `Array`...) that you use as your `ListAdapter`'s data provider.

After this, you call the adapter's `notifyDataSetChanged` method, and your list will be refreshed.